# Solaris T5120 How do i got about installing OS

Tags: installation, operating-systems, solaris

I have a Solaris T5120 it has a DVD Drive

i am new to Solaris or specially with the servers that don't have display port to connect a monitor. So when i power it on i am not sure what to do

Following are images of Front and Back showing what ports are available
[image: Back Panel]
[image: Front Panel]

I see Ser Management and Net management and these take those Ethernet ports

### What i have Already Tried

1. I already tried connecting a ethernet port to it and then checking on my router if i see it connected or if any ports are open but found nothing

### Questions

How would i go about installing Solaris with or without display?

Comment: SER MGT = Serial Management, this is the serial console.  You can use this port along with a serial cable (probably an RJ45 to USB would be easiest) to view the console when the machine boots up.

Comment: is it just a matter of connecting the port and then my windows or OS X would detect it being a serial input? and handle the rest?

Comment: Yeah, if your machine already has a serial port you can connect it directly to that port, otherwise I'd recommend using and serial -> USB adapter. Once its connected to a serial port you would need a terminal program like PuTTY or Tera Term in order to read the data off the serial port.

Comment: thanks, i am going to purchase RJ45 to USB, i don't have a serial port on my mac or windows laptop. appreciate the response

Comment: Would this provide capability for a display? or is there any way to have display? so i can use solaris live cd

Comment: Not a typical display, no, this will only provide you console access.

Comment: thanks please submit this as answer, I already bought a RJ45 to USB connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a Cisco console cable connect a PC or other server has 9pin R232 port to the Ser Mgt port
2. Use a console Terminal like HyperTerminal, set to 9600/8/N/1 to connect to the net management and you can set up the IP address of net mgt
3. After setting the IP you can use SSH to connect to the net mgt and get into console
4. From ser mgt or net mgt, you can boot from DVD ROM

Comment: bought this http://www.ebay.com/itm/111720662946

Comment: Can you please suggest what is console simulator? I was able to get cable and my workstation that has serial port is a Windows XP old machine. I have both of them connected.

Comment: HyperTerminal Helped i am at login prompt

Comment: How to Setup a serial Console connection http://vmnf.no-ip.org/itblog/how-to-setup-a-serial-console-connection/

Comment: I was able to complete step 3 but not sure how to boot from DVD ROM

Comment: Sorry I don't really come to the site very often.

Comment: Got my SunOS installed last week one of my Collegue helped with some commands